# Visual Studio Code - Exclude NPM Scripts in Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code 1.23 you can now run npm scripts from the Explorer window with the setting `"npm.enableScriptExplorer": true`. I know you can exclude whole package.json files with the `"npm.exclude"` setting, but is it possible to exlude just specific scripts from a package.json file? Or at least have them not show up in the Explorer window?

---

**Current:**

>NPM SCRIPTS
  >package.json
    🔧stuff
    🔧start
    🔧build
    🔧stuff2

**Desired:**
(exclude scripts 'stuff' and 'stuff2' from 'package.json')

>NPM SCRIPTS
  >package.json
    🔧start
    🔧build

Comment: Try this : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/869

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be in vscode v1.63: See [Add setting to exclude scripts from NPM scripts view](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/231fe61ab5787ac1cc50052a3099ad861bd2960a).

`config.npm.scriptExplorerExclude`

> "An array of regular expressions that indicate which scripts should be
> excluded from the NPM Scripts view."

In my testing the filter exclusion works on the key/name of the npm script, not on the actual script itself.  So if you had these scripts:

```
 "scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint .",
  "pretest": "npm run lint",
  "test": "node ./test/runTest.js"
 },
```

the filter works on `lint`, `pretest` and `test` NOT on the corresponding scripts themselves (i.e., what you see in the `NPM Scripts` explorer view).  NOT for example on the word `node` (since it isn't part of any script name).

So to filter out `stuff` and `stuff2` in the original question you would have to filter based on something in their script names.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) :

```js
// Enable an explorer view for npm scripts.
      "npm.enableScriptExplorer": false,

// Configure glob patterns for folders that should be excluded from automatic script detection.
      "npm.exclude": "",
```

You can not exclude part of a script in a single file `package.json`

Comment: I know this doesn't contribute to the original question but it is worth noticing that `npm.exclude` patterns are matched against absolute paths, which means an `npm.exclude` value like `./dist/**` or `dist/**` won't work. In order for this to work use `**/dist/**`. Notice that an array of globs may also be used in this setting