# How to exclude other package.json from VSCode npm script scan

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm-scripts

In VSCode, the "NPM SCRIPTS" panel shows the root package.json scripts as expected and desired, however it also shows scripts from a package.json in a hidden `.cache` folder.

Other SO answers advise editing VSCode's `settings.json` to control this area, for example using:

```
`"npm.exclude": "**/@(|vendor|node_modules|bower_components|dist|static)/**",`
```

However adding `|.cache` to this exclude line does nothing; the .cache package.json scripts are still displayed.

Put another way: How can I just see the root package.json NPM scripts in VSCode's "NPM SCRIPTS" panel?

[image]

Comment: did you try using npmignore file? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code - Exclude NPM Scripts in Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50219684/visual-studio-code-exclude-npm-scripts-in-explorer)